# The result of kmeans() does not vary from run to run

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

[image]

I am trying to make several kmeans runs, in order to see the different values that `totss` get. But when I run the following code, I get the same exact result 50 times (n=50).

```
n= 50
k=1
for (i in c(1:n)){

   set.seed(as.numeric(runif(1))) #random seed

   a <- kmeans(na.omit(data[,c(8,22,23,28)]), centers=2)
   print(a$iter)
   print(a$totss)
   print(a$size)
   print(a$centers)

   k=k+1
   remove(a)
}
```

Result

```
*totss      *size1   *size2

64366.21   14080   13061

64366.21   14080   13061

64366.21   14080   13061

64366.21   14080   13061
...
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Picture: I deleted the set.seed() thing, and printed the `a$iter` (number of iterations).

Comment: runif(1) is returning a value between 0 and 1 and set.seed requires an integer.  I suspect you are resetting the random number generator to the same intial value at the start of each loop, thus the calculations are exactly the same.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're actually trying to do. Do you or do you *not* want to set a fixed random seed? In case of the former see @李哲源's answer below; in case of the latter (no fixed seed), simply remove `set.seed(...)` altogether which will result in a random seed each time.

Comment: I changed the "runif(1)" part for "set.seed(round(as.numeric(runif(1)*100)))" and is the same output

Comment: @MauritsEvers Actually I added the "set.seed()" stuff because if I drop it, it's still giving me the same result for all iterations

Comment: Note that index `k` increases by 1 in each iteration, but you are not using it. It doesn't change anything inside your loop

Comment: @JilberUrbina It's for saving the classification on each iteration on a matrix not shown (neither code or the matrix itself)

Answer (score 4):

`set.seed(runif(1))` always gives you `set.seed(0)`. You can try `set.seed(i)` instead.

You can also just use a single `set.seed` outside the loop.

---

> I changed `runif(1)` to `runif(1) * 100` but still got the same output for every run.
>
> I added `set.seed()` because if I drop it, the loop gives me the same result for all iterations.
>
> I understand your point, but the problem is that something is wrong because I am getting the same results in each run / iteration.

Who tells you that `kmeans` always gives random results? It depends on what your data look like. The following example has unambiguously two clusters so that `kmeans` would exhibit no randomness.

```
set.seed(0)
X <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100), 50), matrix(rnorm(100, 10), 50))
plot(X)
```

[image]

```
## 50 run
cl <- replicate(50, kmeans(X, 2), FALSE)

## size[1]
sapply(cl, "[[", c(7, 1))
# [1] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#[26] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50

## size[2]
sapply(cl, "[[", c(7, 2))
# [1] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
#[26] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50

## iter
sapply(cl, "[[", 8)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#[39] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The centers for two clusters are invariant, up to labeling. Sometimes the lower left cluster in the figure is seen as the first cluster, while sometimes the upper right cluster is seen as the first cluster.

```
## center
ctr <- lapply(cl, "[[", 2)
unique(ctr)
#[[1]]
#        [,1]        [,2]
#1 0.02393097  0.02140593    ## lower left cluster is the 1st cluster
#2 9.78910937 10.11978752
#
#[[2]]
#        [,1]        [,2]
#1 9.78910937 10.11978752    ## upper right cluster is the 1st cluster
#2 0.02393097  0.02140593
```

If you want to see some uncertainty, try some "ambiguous" data:

```
X <- matrix(runif(200), 100)
plot(X)
```

[image]

If you ask for 2 clusters from this dataset, `kmeans` can potentially give a different result on each run. If you ask for 3 clusters, the result is more uncertain.

---

**Remark**

Don't compare `totss` from run to run as it is fixed. Compare `withinss` or `tot.withinss` instead which are sensitive to positions of centers.

Comment: I understand your point, but the problem is that something is wrong because I am not getting but the same results in each run/iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Of the data is too extreme, then there may be only a single optimum.

In the part of the data that you showed, the first column is constant (= does not matter), the last one is too low in magnitude to matter. And the other two have just two values. So it's almost certain to find this trivial binary split.

So the problem is your data.